# order of "Possessive and Numeral Adjective"

Tags: adjectives

> He has lost nearly his all many pets.

In the above sentence, there is three adjectives 'his', 'all' and 'many'.
I  am confused to place them appropriately.
So,do their ordering have any effect on sense of the sentence, if yes, how can I fix it?
Please explain it to me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Swap 'all' and 'his', (probably use 'all of') then it will be grammatical

Comment: In real life, I would say 'he has lost almost all of his many pets'

Comment: @Stefan Is there any  rule related to their ordering because it always makes  me confused, also, here 'all' and 'many' together seems odd to me, why can't we just not keep only one whether 'all' or 'many'?

Comment: As far as I know 'all' is not an adjective but I'm not too confident on the precise grammar rules

Comment: @Stefan  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/all

Comment: I guess it is this sense: 'pronoun 9. the whole quantity or amount: He ate all of the peanuts. All are gone.'

Comment: And to answer one of your other questions: you can skip 'many', but 'many' emphasises that he has not just 2-3 pets

Comment: [_Nearly all_] is a unit and must go together. It can be followed by _of,_ or not, but the noun phrase afterwards acts like it's the object of a preposition, with a possessive determiner _his_ and a quantifier _many_ in their respective slots.

Answer (score 1):

> He has lost nearly his all many pets.

I take it he did *not* lose pets that he had almost acquired... such pets would be "nearly his". In this sentence "nearly" modifies "all" so it need to be right before it as "nearly all"

You may say "he has lost nearly all his many pets" but do not say "he has lost his nearly all many pets"-- but as for a rule to tell you why, this is more complicated.

Perhaps you can tell that "nearly all many pets" is wrong. It wants to be either "nearly all *of the* many pets" (or in this case "nearly all *of* his many pets") The "of" needed (or implied) because you are saying two different things about the pets. (1) He has many pets and (2) he lost nearly all of them. It is as if the "nearly all" modifies how he lost them, but "many" is about all his pets;  "many" tells you something about even the pets that were not lost.

I think this is better with the "of"-- but once you have them in the correct order, it can be written with or without the "of". Hence: **He has lost nearly all** (of) **his many pets.**